# How to change readline scroll behaviour on OS X?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mysql, scrolling, readline

I'm SSHing in Mac OS X Terminal to two ubuntu servers, then I connect to various readline-enabled shells, like MySQL or Mongo clients.

Recently, it seems that somehow the scroll behaviour changed. when I scroll with the mouse, instead of being able to page up as I'd expect, the readline itself scrolls between commands.

That is, instead of seeing the results on the top of the SQL/mongo result list, I scroll back one command in the commandline, which is not what I'd like to do.

To my knowledge, neither the servers (Ubuntu 14.04) neither my mac was changed significantly.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like this: some terminal emulators can be told to pretend that wheel-mouse events are up/down arrows rather than page-scrolling.  While there may be a special control sequence or configuration setting (such as [alternateScroll](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97219/e-option-with-various-terminal-emulators) with xterm), generally that is activated by the switch to/from full-screen (or the alternate screen) in the terminal description.

While Apple provides no documentation for Terminal.app's escape sequences, I see in [Yosemite introduces per-line scrolling in the Terminal](http://www.macissues.com/2014/06/10/yosemite-introduces-per-line-scrolling-in-the-terminal/) a hint that they have done this also.

If this is the situation, then you should be able to work around by using a terminal description omitting the 47 or 1049 controls from the `smcup` and `rmcup` capabilities (and depending on whether you use `screen`, `tmux` or neither, the advice varies on how to do this — some of the advice is poor, specifically when it says to just remove the capabilities).